# Rest : Response message is null

Tags: java, spring, rest, jmeter

I have a rest API which I am testing using Jmeter. The response message assertion for message "OK" is failing.

Following are the response headers I see

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=BE7C763B232F61E6DCECFSDEDEDB;path=/test-service;HttpOnly
X-Application-Context: test-service:DEFAULT,dev:8098
Link: 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 15 Feb 2017 09:14:30 GMT
```

Sampler Result

```
Sample Start: 2017-02-15 14:44:26 IST
Load time: 4422
Latency: 4418
Size in bytes: 4368
Headers size in bytes: 500
Body size in bytes: 3868
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 200
Response message:
```

When I test it through postman I get proper result

[image]

Can someone tell why this might be happening?

Note :
My Application is a spring boot app.

update :
this is not happening only in jmeter. I tried using Advance rest client
Got only the status code
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your response assertion is configured like the one given below, it shouldn't be failing. In case, if you are looking for the entire text "HTTP/1.1 200", ensure that "Response Headers" radio button is checked along with "Contains" in the pattern matching rules with text as "HTTP/1.1 200"

[image]

Comment: This is response code assertion I am talking about response message assertion.

Comment: Your HTTP return code and the headers will go under response headers. Only response body will go under Response Message. Post a screenshot of your configuration

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not jmeter issue. 
HTTP/2 does not define a way to carry the version or reason phrase that is included in an HTTP/1.1 status line.
    https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6548
This is actually a Tomcat 8.5 issue as it starts to support HTTP/2 specifications.
To quote the comment in the relevant part of the Tomcat "Clients should ignore it (RFC 7230) and it just wastes bytes."